# add class name based on text content contained in another div

Tags: class, text

I want to be able to add the first word from the text in a div and make it part of a class of a different div.

The first word from id"categoryname" needs to be the first word in the class added to id"category_icon".  I also want to make sure it is always lower case.  Thank you

Example:

```
<li id="categoryname">Softball Gifts</li>

$('#category_icon').addClass('***ADD-SOFTBALL-HERE***_category_icon');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are 100% sure about the <li>'s content (that is there will be only text inside), you can use its inner html and parse it as a simple string:

```
var firstWord = $("#categoryname").html().split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();

$('#category_icon').addClass(firstWord + '_category_icon');
```

Comment: That was awesome.  Thanks again.  You just saved me a lot of time.